# Unable to access file on local http-server from javascript fs

Tags: javascript, fs, simplehttpserver, readdir

I'm trying to access the directory listing of files from the http-server webserver listing configured on the localhost:4040.

I have uploaded files using the http-server to mimic a file server for testing.  When I use fs to access the files in the folder with the full URL (e.g. http://localhost:4040/folder1/), I get the following error:-

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'http://localhost:4040/folder1/'

The directory listing is accessible if I browse the same URL through the web browser.

```
fs
.readdirSync(imagePath)
.forEach((filename, index) => {
   console.log(filename
   files.push({path: imagePath, fileName: filename, fullFileName: imagePath + '/' + filename})
          });
```

Comment: Does File System even work like that? I'd throw an error too, if it was purposed for your directory and not a URL but I could be wrong.

Comment: You should fetch the data.

Comment: The web path is used to make client -> server request.  Your server code should be using file path not web path